при разбивке sdb висит на Creating journal
    kostya@kostya-nevynnyi:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.38.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 58,05 GiB, 62329454592 bytes, 121737216 sectors
Disk model: FLASH DRIVE     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5cbacba3

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 40579071 40577024 19,3G 83 Linux

Command (m for help): d
Selected partition 1
Partition 1 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 58,05 GiB, 62329454592 bytes, 121737216 sectors
Disk model: FLASH DRIVE     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5cbacba3

Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 1
First sector (2048-121737215, default 2048): 
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-121737215, default 121737215): 

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 58 GiB.

Command (m for help): n
All space for primary partitions is in use.

Command (m for help): d
Selected partition 1
Partition 1 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 58,05 GiB, 62329454592 bytes, 121737216 sectors
Disk model: FLASH DRIVE     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5cbacba3

Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 1
First sector (2048-121737215, default 2048): 
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-121737215, default 121737215): +14G

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 14 GiB.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 58,05 GiB, 62329454592 bytes, 121737216 sectors
Disk model: FLASH DRIVE     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5cbacba3

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 29362175 29360128  14G 83 Linux

Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (1 primary, 0 extended, 3 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): p
Partition number (2-4, default 2): 2
First sector (29362176-121737215, default 29362176): 
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (29362176-121737215, default 121737215): +14G

Created a new partition 2 of type 'Linux' and of size 14 GiB.

Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (2 primary, 0 extended, 2 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): p
Partition number (3,4, default 3): 3
First sector (58722304-121737215, default 58722304): 
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (58722304-121737215, default 121737215): +14G

Created a new partition 3 of type 'Linux' and of size 14 GiB.

Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (3 primary, 0 extended, 1 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default e): p

Selected partition 4
First sector (88082432-121737215, default 88082432): 
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (88082432-121737215, default 121737215): 

Created a new partition 4 of type 'Linux' and of size 16 GiB.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 58,05 GiB, 62329454592 bytes, 121737216 sectors
Disk model: FLASH DRIVE     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5cbacba3

Device     Boot    Start       End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           2048  29362175 29360128  14G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       29362176  58722303 29360128  14G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb3       58722304  88082431 29360128  14G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb4       88082432 121737215 33654784  16G 83 Linux

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.

kostya@kostya-nevynnyi:~$ sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb1
mke2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
Creating filesystem with 3670016 4k blocks and 917504 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 69a49646-4716-4e65-94e1-e1238375a8f4
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (16384 blocks): 

сутку ждал, что делать? как реанимировать usb?

Купи новую фллешку

дорогие )) сколько помню Linux а он у меня с епохи XP проблема с записью, раньше болванки портил сейчас флешки
